# Blocking waiting of Task.WaitAll

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm actually studying `async/wait` and trying to see for myself the benefit of `await Task.WhenAll` versus `Task.WaitAll` in CPU bound operations. As everyone write that `Task.WaitAll` provides a blocking wait while `await Task.WhenAll` provides a non-blocking wait.

I created an example in which I wanted to replace `Task.WaitAll` with an `await Task.WhenAll` and see with my own eyes that there was one more free thread. But I see that even `Task.WaitAll` does not block the thread. And my question is related to this. In the case of `Task.WaitAll`, I see that in the same thread in which `Task.WaitAll` is executed, another task is being executed. But if I include `Thread.Sleep` or `while (true)` instead of `Task.WaitAll`, then the behavior of the program becomes as expected.

I thought that the `Main` method will create task MyTask (-1 worker thread), which will create 16 tasks conditionally B1-B16 (-15 worker threads since 1 worker thread is busy with task MyTask, and there are 16 worker threads in total), task MyTask will have a blocking wait `Task.WaitAll` and I will see 15 out of 16 running tasks. But I see all 16 running tasks and one of them is running on the same thread that task MyTask is running on.

**Question**.
Why does `Task.WaitAll` not block the thread in which it is executed in this example, unlike `Thread.Sleep` or `while (true)`? Can someone explain step by step how the code of two tasks in thread 4 works in case of using `Task.WaitAll`? Why is the thread in which task MyTask runs also used by task conditionally B16?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Main                Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

            int ProcessorCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(ProcessorCount, ProcessorCount);
            int Counter = 0;
            List<Task> MyListForTask = new List<Task>();

            void MyMethod()
            {
                lock (MyListForTask)
                {
                    Counter++;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Counter: {Counter}        Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                }
                
                //Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue);
                while (true) { };
            }

            Task MyTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"MyTask            Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}\n");

                for (int i = 0; i < ProcessorCount; i++)
                {
                    MyListForTask.Add(Task.Run(MyMethod));
                }

                //Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue);
                //while (true) { };
                Task.WaitAll(MyListForTask.ToArray());                
            });

            MyTask.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check out [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/taskcreationoptions-preferfairness/ "TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness") article by Stephen Toub. My guess is that the `MyTask.Wait()` is "stealing" work from one of the other tasks in the list. You might want to test this hypothesis by replacing the `Task.Run` with the `Task.Factory.StartNew`, and passing the `TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness` option.

Comment: And this theft depends on whether I use `Task.WaitAll` or `Thread.Sleep` in `MyTask`? Sounds weird... I replaced `MyTask.Wait()` with `Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue)`, nothing changed.

Comment: Simply by using `Thread.Sleep` you make all observations invalid. Tasks aren't threads, they're essentially promises/job descriptions. Tasks run on reusable threadpool threads. Calling `Thread.Sleep` not only blocks those threads, it removes them from the OS's scheduling, forcing the runtime to create new ones. If you want to emulate waiting use `Thread.SpinWait` at least.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, In debugging in the windows of tasks and threads, it is clearly seen that in the case of `Thread.Sleep` instead of `Task.WaitAll` 16 tasks are started and one is scheduled, in the case of `Task.WaitAll` instead of `Thread.Sleep` all 17 tasks are started and blocked. Does this refer to an invalid observation? I look not only at the console. One task did not have enough flow. Can you explain step by step how the code of the two tasks in thread 4 works in case of using Task.WaitAll?

Comment: If you want to see what's actually going on use the [Concurrency Visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/concurrency-visualizer?view=vs-2022) in VS. Using a file or the console to indirectly monitor threads isn't just slow, it also adds an unexpected synchronization. I'll repeat this though - tasks aren't threads. They're a promise that something will complete and maybe produce a value in the future. They may not even use a thread to complete. If they use a thread, that may or may not come from the thread pool.

Comment: One way this impacts the results is that tasks don't start running when `Task.Run` is called. That schedules the *promise* for execution, it doesn't start it. This means that the `My Task` that creates the workers may finish before all those `Counter` themselves start, releasing its thread. This threadpool thread is now free to serve one of the `Counter` tasks.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, What do you mean they don't start, I don't understand what you're talking about? There is a specific example. In one case, 15 tasks are running, in the other 16, this can be seen in the console, this can be seen in debugging. While I draw conclusions that everyone who wrote something does not understand what is happening, like me, and there is nothing more than guesswork.

Comment: The question's code imposes an extremely low limit which impacts results for another reason - `ProcessorCount` is affected by hyperthreading, so an 8-core HT CPU will report 16 cores. Obviously `Thread.Sleep` isn't HT friendly. In the screenshot 16 `Counter` tasks are quickly created and `My Task` exits. Nothing else had a chance to get scheduled by that time (the OS scheduler needs CPU cycles too), so when `My Task` completes its thread becomes available to server `Counter 9`. The `Concurrency Visualizer` will show this as 8 or 16 swimlanes with the tasks executing on each core at each point

Comment: @NikVladi there's no guesswork. Tasks were creates 12 years ago. Their behavior is well known. I repeat, they aren't threads. They're promises. I don't use that name lightly - that's what they're called in other languages too. How that promise gets processed depends on the type of task, the runtime and language. In .NET they're processed through a TaskScheduler. The default TaskScheduler will use threads from the thread pool *but that's not the only option*. There are single-threaded schedulers, limited schedulers, IO schedulers and more. The tasks know nothing about threads

Comment: There were quite a lot of blog post between 2007 and 2012 about this but unfortunately many were lost due to MSDN changes and reorganizations. Stephen Toub wrote several articles explaining tasks and schedulers [like this one](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/) that explains possible scheduler alternatives. You can find the [.NET Parallel team's blog posts here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/) from 2007 until it was merged into the .NET core team. Stephen Cleary's book and articles are a great guide too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Okay, you won. I replaced `Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue)` with `while (true)` in `MyMethod`. `Task.WaitAll` still doesn't block the thread and he is available for the sixteenth task. 16 tasks execute `MyMethod`. Now we cannot say that `Thread.Sleep` is to blame. What's the matter now?

Comment: Features under the hood in .NET. Answer here https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1470626/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-task-waitall

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of `multithreading` / `asynchronous` programming is to use your CPU resources as effectively as possible and you do not care about the order of operation.

There's no guarantee that the order the Tasks were started in, they will also be completed in.

`Thread.Sleep`, as the name implies, actively blocks the CPU thread (will not pick up another task) and waits until the required condition has been met (x time passed) before executing the task - and only then picking another task. In short, Thread.Sleep prevents `asynchronous` behavior from occuring.

Here you can see more intuitively what each one will do. Output will not be 1-100 consecutively, but random.

The WhenAll even prints the DoSomethingElse first since the Tasks are still starting/being executed.

The WaitAll will wait for the tasks before printing DoSomethingElse even though that slows down execution.

The Sleep, as mentioned, only adds time. You can put a thread to sleep in an async or 'sync' method, but the only thing it does is add execution time to your program. The only difference is that in an async other available threads in will pick up the slack (if available).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Fiddle

{
    public class Program
    {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var ladieDo = new DoSomething();
        ladieDo.RunAsyncAndDontAwaitCompletion();

        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        ladieDo.RunAsyncAndAwaitCompletionOfAll();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    public class DoSomething
    {
        public void RunAsyncAndDontAwaitCompletion()
        {
            var proces = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            Console.WriteLine("Threads:" + proces.Threads);
            var ints = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();

            // Will report back when its done, but wont wait for everything
            Task.WhenAll(ints.Select(a => Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(a))));

            // This line will be executed as soon as a Thread opens up, regardless of whether the above tasks have been completed
            Console.WriteLine("DoSomethingElse");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void RunAsyncAndAwaitCompletionOfAll()
        {
            var proces = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            Console.WriteLine("Threads:" + proces.Threads);
            var ints = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();

            // wait untill all these tasks are done
            Task.WaitAll(ints.Select(a => Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(a))).ToArray());

            // only once above tasks are done (regardless of order), write this
            Console.WriteLine("DoSomethingElse");
        }

        public void EachTaskWillRunSynchronously()
        {
            var proces = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            Console.WriteLine("Threads:" + proces.Threads);
            var ints = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();

            foreach (int i in ints)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                
                // The below line will just add more time in between each output
                //Thread.Sleep(10);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("DoSomethingElse");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Output:

```
DoSomethingElse
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
5
....
    89
90
91
92
93
94
88
84
97
98
96
100
99
95
DoSomethingElse
```

Comment: Then what is the blocking wait for `Task.WaitAll`?

Comment: @NikVladi only after all the results are in, will it continue with the next line of code (in your case `MyTask.Wait()`. 

Since order of processing/output is not guaranteed in asynchronous calls, they are usually sorted afterwards (before being displayed).

Comment: In the first case, I see that the method from MyTask was launched in the 4th thread. Further, the method from MyTask creates new tasks, that is, the 4th thread should be occupied with just this. After that, in the method from MyTask in the 4th thread, Task.WaitAll should work, which should block the 4th thread? Am I right? Can you explain step by step how the code works by talking about thread 4? And how does it happen that in the 4th thread, which should always be busy, a method from another task is executed?

Comment: @NikVladi I'll write up a better example, give me a few min.

Comment: Thank you for your work, but I'm sorry, I don't understand at all what is the connection between your example and my question. My example clearly demonstrates that Thread.Sleep actually blocks the thread, but Task.WaitAll does not. How did I get it? I use Thread.Sleep and it works 15 tasks, and when I use Task.WaitAll instead it works 16 tasks. Means there is one more free stream. Why? Everyone writes that Task.WaitAll is a blocking wait. But the thread is not blocked. And I asked for a step by step explanation of how the code in my example works in thread 4.